# Angular using $routParams to filter json data retrived

Tags: json, angularjs, angular-routing

I'd like to filter the JSON being displayed by the route param provided. I have a list page which displays all of the json data and a detail page which I would like to just display the json matching the id in the routeparam.

This is my service:

```
app.factory("HC", ["$resource", function($resource) {
    return {
        API: $resource('/api/hc')
    }
}]);
```

This is my controller which is working for displaying all of the results. How could I filter these by the requestParams?

```
app.controller('servicesDetail', ['$scope', 'HC', '$resource', '$routeParams', function ($scope, HC, $resource, $routeParams ) { 


  HC.API.query(function(results) {
        $scope.services = results;
    });

  $scope.services = []

}]);
```

And here are my routes

```
.when('/services', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/services.html',
            controller: 'servicesController'
        })

    .when('/services/:serviceId', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/servicedetail.html',
        controller: 'servicesDetail'
    })
```

Comment: can you post your json  ?

Comment: currently my json is very simple for configuring purposes.
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53bc36b8b7bbbf77208dec62"), "name" : "this is from the client", "__v" : 0 }

Answer (score 0):

Your json is not valid but in case it has format like that :

```
{ "_id" : "53bc36b8b7bbbf77208dec62", "name" : "this is from the client", "__v" : 0 }
```

you can use **filterFilter** service please see demo here http://jsbin.com/somob/1/edit?html,js,output

but the best option is send serviceId to server and get a single service from server instead array of services and filter them after

app.controller('servicesDetail', ['$scope', 'HC', '$resource', '$routeParams', 'filterFilter',

function ($scope, HC, $resource, $routeParams, filterFilter) {

```
$scope.services = [];
HC.API.query(function (results) {
    $scope.services = results;
});



$scope.serviceId = $routeParams.serviceId;

$scope.serviceById = filterFilter($scope.services, {
    _id: $routeParams.serviceId
});
```

}]);
html:

```
<!--just for testing -->
    <p>ServiceId : {{serviceId }}</p>

    <pre>{{serviceById |json}}</pre>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. For some reason in my rendered view an empty array is returned.

Comment: @byrdr please update your view like in answer it will be easier to find what is wrong

Comment: The testing returned this:
ServiceId :
[
  {
    "_id": "53bc36b8b7bbbf77208dec62",
    "name": "this is from the client",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "53bc36bbb7bbbf77208dec63",
    "name": "this is from the client",
    "__v": 0
  }
]
[]